# How to check if all of an array's elements are the same

Tags: java, arrays

How can you know that all of the elements in an array are the same?
For example,
a[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

How can you know that all elements in a[] are the same?
I'm a noob, please answer in easy terms. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a particular language?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot. It's java.

Answer (score 8):

Compare the value of each cell in the array with one of the cells, eg. the first cell. If all comparisons show that the values are the same then then all values in the entire array are the same.

Here is an example of what it could look like:

```
public static boolean allElementsTheSame(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        int first = array[0];
        for (int element : array) {
            if (element != first) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it in c ok?
a[] is the array
allEquals is a booleans
ArrayLenght the dimension of the array

```
BOOL allEquals = true;

for (int i=1; i<ArrayLenght; i++) {
    if (a[i-1] != a[i])
        allEquals = false;
}
```

now in allEquals you have true if all elements are equals, false otherwise.

Comment: There is no need to iterate over all the array, when you get the first disagree you can break the cicle.